# Mix blend mode not working for svg element in firefox

Tags: css, angular, svg

I have a svg on top of an img tag. The svg has an element with mix blend mode: color to blend with the img:

```
<g id="myitem" style="mix-blend-mode:color">
  <path d="M456 410.5L2.5 497L3 ... 410.5Z" fill="white"/>
</g>
```

This code works perfectly on Chrome it blends and create a greyscale filter but on Firefox it just can't blend and the mix blend mode doesn't work at all. Result in the element has fill="white" so it has white color. Is there a way to fix for Firefox?

Comment: Please show us a full example. Not just part of the file.

Answer (score 0):

May be you should set style mixBlendMode field

Before:[< GridSvg/>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5IedO.png)

After:[< GridSvg style={{mixBlendMode:'screen'}}/>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CIkT4.png)

Example via React, idk how do it via angular

Comment: Old question I forgot to update the answer. I figured it out by adding the blend mode directly to svg element and not to any group elements. Thanks for commenting though